# Resharper - force braces but stack usings in Code Cleanup

Tags: c#, resharper, using, using-statement, code-cleanup

Is it possible to configure Resharper's Code Cleanup not only to require braces on a C# `using` statement, but also to stack the `using` statements without nesting indents and braces?

For example, if I started with code that looks like this:

```
using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
{
    using (var repo = new Repository(uow)) repo.Add(user);
}
```

The resulting format I want is:

```
using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
using (var repo = new Repository(uow))
{
    repo.Add(user);
}
```

Namely:

- `repo.Add(user)` is inside braces
- two `using`s do not cause two levels of braces

Comment: No braces I can understand, but indents? Makes it easier to misunderstand what is going on IMO.

Comment: Weirdly enough I was just trying this and it formats for me exactly as you want.  No indents, no braces.  So i'm curious if I've misunderstood your question.  What is the format of the code you want to reformat w/ resharper?

Comment: And by force, are you suggesting that you want it to throw compiler errors?  If this is the case, I'd suggest using StyleCop.

Comment: ReSharper does exactly what you expect on my machine, what version do you use?

Comment: @paqogomez I have updated the question to clarify that I'm looking for Code Cleanup configuration, not enforcement a la StyleCop.

Comment: @Console I am using Resharper 8.2